# How should I handle sql schema management for a clojure project?

Tags: mysql, sql, clojure, database-migration, korma

I'm working on a web project in clojure and I will have a mysql database storing information.  I plan on using [Korma](http://sqlkorma.com/) for data CRUD but I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage actually creating the tables.

I'm inclined to just write a bash script that runs the `CREATE TABLE` commands, but I feel like this isn't the proper way to do things, and doesn't allow for future migrations.  Should I use a Clojure library for this?  Bash?  Something else entirely?

Comment: Answers to questions like "what is the best way?" are most often "there is no one".

Comment: have a look at http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/ (there is a section about Database Migration).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this one [Migratus](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus), this is used in luminus(A web framework), And I think this might help.

Answer (score 0):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) is a popular tool for database migrations in the Java world. There is also a [clj-liquibase](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/clj-liquibase) project which uses EDN and uses liquibase internally, but I've never used it.